# android local time and timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp

hi to all how can i get the currant time and date for android and compare it with a timestamp i have

Answer (score 2):

Current Timestamp (Milliseconds)

```
long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: The question implies an attempt to measure elapsed time by comparing timestamps.  The documentation you link to specifically says:
"""This method shouldn't be used for measuring timeouts or other elapsed time measurements, as changing the system time can affect the results."""

Answer (score 1):

The reference page you want is [Android SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).  It recommends using either uptimeMillis or elapsedRealtime, depending on whether your app needs to count time during deep sleep or not.

```
long etime = 0;
final long time1 = uptimeMillis();
/* do something */
final long time2 = uptimeMillis();
if (time2 < time1) {
    etime = Long.MAX_VALUE - time1 + time2;
} else {
    etime = time2 - time1;
}
```

Note: the value returned *can* wrap because long isn't infinite; check for a negative value as above.